# How do I make a beep sound in Android using Delphi and the API?

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

After having a look at the Androidapi.JNI.Media.pas, I coded the following procedure:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  AndroidApi.JNI.Media;

procedure Sound(ADuration: Integer);

implementation

procedure Sound(ADuration: Integer);
var
  Volume: Integer;
  StreamType: Integer;
  ToneType: Integer;
  ToneGenerator: JToneGenerator;
begin

  Volume := TJToneGenerator.JavaClass.MAX_VOLUME;

  StreamType := ?
  ToneType := TJToneGenerator.JavaClass.TONE_DTMF_0;

  ToneGenerator := TJToneGenerator.JavaClass.init(StreamType, Volume);
  ToneGenerator.startTone(ToneType, ADuration);

end;
```

but I can't figure out how to set a value for the StreamType?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. With ben75's answer below, my function is complete - and it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream type identify the *stream* on which the beep must be played. It is an integer between 0 and 4 :

- STREAM_VOICE_CALL (0)
- STREAM_SYSTEM (1)
- STREAM_RING (2)
- STREAM_MUSIC(3)
- STREAM_ALARM(4)

Comment: Thanks. But this code  `StreamType := STREAM_ALARM;` won't compile.

Comment: I don't know delphi, but what about `StreamType := 4` ? or better `StreamType := TJAudioManager.JavaClass.STREAM_ALARM`

Comment: Aha!. Yes, both of those ideas work. Now I understand.