# Crossplatform audio support in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, audio, firemonkey

I'm running Delphi Tokyo and I'm looking for a way to play audio on Windows and Android (and maybe at some point iOS).

On Windows I can do with something like `PlaySound(PChar(ResourceName), 0, SND_RESOURCE or SND_ASYNC)`, but I'm stuck on Android.  I've tried TMediaPlayer, but it takes about a second before it starts playing, which is too long for a mouse click or screen tap.

Basically I've built a Minesweeper clone and I'm looking for sound support (if you want to know the background).

Suggestions?

Comment: You don't show how you use media player - you only show us the code that works! Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Does this help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938946)?

Comment: MediaPlayer plays mp3's straight away (i.e. no delay) for me. Perhaps you might want to share the sound file and/or the code you're using

Comment: I should recommend you to use Delphi Berlin for Android, instead of Tokyo, because it's buggy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a few arcade game demos that have audio classes that you can use.  See https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiArcadeGames

You can also see [Is there an alternative to TMediaPlayer for multi platform rapid sound effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734013) for a description of some issues encountered on Android with the audio management class in these demos.

With the latest version of the audio manager provided in the games samples, the developer simply removes all notifications/checking that an audio file is actually loaded and ready to play. I personally did not like the idea of simply expecting the audio to be ready to play.

My audio management classes are a bit too complicated to simply post, but if you need this functionality hopefully this bit of pseudo code can offer some clues on how I addressed the short comings of the `AudioManager` provided in the game demos.

The idea is to create a callback in my main application that is invoked when an audio file is ready to play. With a bit of web search, I found the following links to be helpful references for my implementation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool

https://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-android-s-soundpool-class-a-tutorial.html

1 - Define a notification type that will provide sufficient info on the audio file that is ready to play.  Mine looks like this:

```pascal
TSoundLoadedEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; ASoundID: integer; AStatus: Integer) of object;
```

2 - As per the documentation, define a class that handles `JSoundPool_OnLoadCompleteListener`.  Note that the class utilizes our custom event defined as `TSoundLoadedEvent`, which means that the `AudioManager` will have to implement this callback:

```pascal
TMyAudioLoadedListener = class(TJavaLocal, JSoundPool_OnLoadCompleteListener)
  private
    FSoundPool       : JSoundPool;
    FOnJLoadCompleted : TSoundLoadedEvent;
  public
    procedure onLoadComplete(soundPool: JSoundPool; sampleId,status: Integer); cdecl;
    property  OnLoadCompleted: TSoundLoadedEvent read FOnJLoadCompleted write FOnJLoadCompleted;
    property  SoundPool: JSoundPool read FSoundPool;
  end;

...

procedure TMyAudioLoadedListener.onLoadComplete(soundPool: JSoundPool; sampleId, status: Integer);
begin
  FSoundPool := soundPool;
  if Assigned(FOnJLoadCompleted) then
    FOnJLoadCompleted(Self, sampleID, status);
end;
```

3 - Modify the audio manager class to implement the listener:

```pascal
  TAudioManager = Class
    Private
      fAudioMgr              : JAudioManager;
      fSoundPool             : JSoundPool;
      fmyAudioLoadedListener : TMyAudioLoadedListener;
      fOnPlatformLoadComplete : TSoundLoadedEvent;
    Public
      Constructor Create; override;
      ...
      procedure DoOnLoadComplete(Sender: TObject; sampleId: Integer; status: Integer);
      ...
      property  OnLoadComplete: TSoundLoadedEvent read fOnPlatformLoadComplete write fOnPlatformLoadComplete;
```

4 - Implement the `JSoundPool` listener and wire the callback from the listener to our `AudioManager`:

```pascal
constructor TAudioManger.Create;
begin
  ...
  //create our listener
  fmyAudioLoadedListener := TMyAudioLoadedListener.Create;

  // set the listener callback 
  fmyAudioLoadedListener.OnLoadCompleted := DoOnLoadComplete;

  // inform JSoundPool that we have a listener
  fSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener( fmyAudioLoadedListener ); 
  ...
```

And

```
procedure TAudioManager.DoOnLoadComplete(Sender: TObject; sampleId: Integer; status: Integer);
begin
  if Succeeded(status) then  //remove this if you want all notifications
  begin
    if Assigned(Self.fOnPlatformLoadComplete) then
      fOnPlatformLoadComplete( self, sampleID, status );
  end;
end;
```

5 - Last thing is to implement a callback in the main application:

```pascal
TMainForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  fAudioMgr   :  TAudioManager;
  ...
  procedure OnSoundLoaded(Sender: TObject; ASoundID: integer; AStatus: integer);
```

Then, where you create the `AudioManager`, assign the new `TSoundLoadedEvent` to a local procedure that I called `OnSoundLoaded`:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
...
begin
  ...
  fAudioMgr := TAudioManager.Create;
  fAudioMgr.OnSoundLoaded := OnSoundLoaded;
```

Now, when an audio file is ready to play, you should get notified:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.OnSoundLoaded(Sender: TObject; ASoundID: integer; AStatus: integer);
begin
  // track IDs when loading sounds to identify which one is ready
  // check status to confirm that the audio was loadded successfully
end;
```

This is definitely only bits and pieces, but hopefully can be helpful.