# How to set the playback speed of TMediaPlayer?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm using Delphi 10.4 for developing an Android mobile application. I'm using the `TMediaPlayer` component for playing MP3 files. I need to set the playback speed of the media files as 1x, 2x, and 4x. I did not find any sample code regarding this. How can I implement this feature?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer_Properties) such a feature does not exist. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `TMediaPlayer` uses the native `MediaPlayer` class from Android (imported as `JMediaPlayer`) which does not have the ability to change the playback rate. There is another class called [`SoundPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate(int,%20float)) that does, so you'd need to use an instance of that

Comment: You might like to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356644/3164070